# Output string to log file, then pipe to function as argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, echo, bash-functions

So I am trying to echo a string out to a log file and also pass that echo'd string over to a function along with other arguments as well. I can't seem to figure out how to do it or find any answers on here. Here is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash

test() {
   INPUT=$(cat)
   echo "IT WORKED $INPUT $1 $2"
}

echo "TEST2" > test.log | cat | test "Hi " "John"
```

My Output

```
IT WORKED  Hi  John
```

Comment: splitting output usually requires something like `tee`

Comment: I tried working with tee as well, however I wasn't able to get it. Something like `echo "TEST2" | tee test.log > test "Hi " "John` didn't work

Comment: The whole point of `tee` is to have its standard output be a pipe.  If you say `tee (filename) > test …`, that will create a file called `test`, which is not what you want. P.S. Put everything that you tried *into the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test() {
   INPUT=$(cat)
   echo "IT WORKED $INPUT $1 $2"
}
echo TEST2 | tee test.log  | test Hi John
```

output: `IT WORKED TEST2 Hi John`

test.log contents: `TEST2`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I could've sworn I did that, but I must've did something complete different. ++